# JSON Array NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

What would be the best way to parse this in an Android app? I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException when I run the app. Please take a look at my code and let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
{"begin":[{"id":1,"name":"Bob","size":2}],"open":[{"id":1,"name":"Mike","size":2}]}
```

This is the code that I have.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public MainFragment() {}

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private String url = "URL...";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_BEGIN = "begin";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SIZE = "size";

    JSONArray begin = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        new JSONParse().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);
                JSONObject c = begin.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String size = c.getString(TAG_SIZE);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the activity I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException
at
...$MainFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:399)
at
...$MainFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:373)
```

Which is...

```
begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);
```

and...

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
```

Comment: What is `TAG_CURRENT`?

Comment: I see no "current = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);" in the onPostExecute method. I see "begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CURRENT);"

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Whoops @ShobhitPuri. TAG_CURRENT should have been changed to TAG_BEGIN. I just forgot to rename it.

Comment: @WilliamRiley I renamed some of my code. Please regard current as begin. I just forgot to change that part.

Comment: And its still not working?

Comment: Just check if in `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` `json` is not null

Comment: @Simon Here you go http://pastie.org/8483501

Comment: @WilliamRiley still not working.

Comment: Use Volley: http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html

Comment: No links please.  Edit your question and paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JSON response isn't returning null.

This could also cause NullPointerException:

> ```
>         begin = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CURRENT);
> ```

Comment: How would I make sure that it isn't returning null?

Answer (score 0):

To debug:

Place a breakpoint at line 399: (assumed to be the begin=json.getJSONArray(TAG_BEGIN);) by double clicking the line number "399" if you have them displayed, otherwise, just click the left of the document at that line.

Run in debug mode (Looks like a little bug) duh! hahaha. When it comes to execution of that code the application will stop and you can go back to your code and show the window called "Expressions".

If that window isnt visible, click "Window" > "Show View" > Other > Debug > Expressions. Then you can add expressions to that list to see what is null.

Add json to the list of expressions, and make sure that it has the JSON string.

This is crazy, and a lot to explain, but hopefully, it helps you get started on debugging. You MUST know how to debug to write apps.

Comment: Its a bit to talk through, need to contact me via some kind of instant messenger, or chat. But you havent the reuptation for chat here.